# Create a record using modal bootstrap and ajax?

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I'm making a simple blog using Laravel 5.4. I want to know how to create a record with ajax and modal bootstrap so that the page doesn't have to reload every single time a record is added ? I tried following tutorials on the net but I'm still unable to make it working on my project (because I'm really bad at JS).

My current store method :

```
public function store(Request $request) {
        $input = $request->all();
        $validator = Validator::make($input, [
                    'title' => 'required|string'
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput()->with($this->addTagError);
        } else {
            $tag = Tag::create($input);
        }
        return redirect()->route('tagsindex')->with($this->addTagSuccess);
    }
```

The route :

```
Route::post('dashboard/tags', 'TagCon@store')->name('tagstore');
```

The view :

```
<div class="alert alert-info fade in">
   <h4>Manage Blog Tags From Here</h4>
     <p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addModal">Add a new Tag</button>
     </p>
     <!-- Add Modal start -->
     <div class="modal fade" id="addModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
           <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-header">
                   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Add a new Tag</h4>
               </div>
               <form action="{{ route('tagstore') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                  <div class="modal-body">
                  {{ csrf_field() }}
                      <div class="form-group">
                         <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('title') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                         <label class="control-label">Tag Name<span style="color: red">*</span> :</label>
                         <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control" value="{{old('title')}}" />
                         @if ($errors->has('title'))
                         <span class="help-block">
                         <strong>{{ $errors->first('title') }}</strong>
                         </span>
                         @endif
                         </div>
                      </div>
                   </div>
               <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info"><span id="" class='glyphicon glyphicon-check'></span> Submit</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal"><span id="" class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> Cancel</button>
               </div>
               </form>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   <!-- add modal code ends -->
    </div>

<div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-dark mb30">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>#</th>
                                    <th>Tags Name</th>
                                    <th style="text-align: center">Action</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach($tags as $indexKey => $t)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ $indexKey+1 }}</td>
                                    <td><a href="{{ url('dashboard/tags/' . $t->titleslug) }}">{{$t->title}}</a> ({{$t->posts->count()}})</td>
                                    <td class="table-action">
                                        <a href="{{url('dashboard/tags/'. $t->id .'/edit')}}" class="tooltips" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit">
                                            <button style=" background: none;">
                                                <i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                            </button>
                                        </a>
                                        <a class="tooltips" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete">
                                            <form action="{{route('tagdestroy', $t->id)}}" method="POST">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
                                                <button type="submit" style=" background: none;" onclick="return confirm('Anda yakin ?');">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                </button>
                                            </form>
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div><!-- table-responsive -->
                </div><!-- col-md-6 -->
```

The code above works but it will still reloading the page every time a record is added. Sorry that I do not put a single ajax code here because as I said before I don't even know where to start. I'm sure a single example that working with my app will be enough for me to learn it and then create it on my own next time.

Answer (score 0):

I'll show you an example of something I built in an actual application. Although this was built with Laravel 5.2, I'm sure you'll be able to figure it out. This is built using Bootstrap, Javascript and jQuery. Since it seems you're already familiar with Bootstrap, you might want to check out the links below.

- A good place [to get started on Javascript might be here](http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/javascript-basics).
- Similarly, a place [to get started on jQuery might be here](http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/jquery-basics).

Below here you will find some code pieces you'll probably be able to use.

**Basic modal HTML**

```
<div id="userModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Create user</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="userForm" class="form-horizontal">
            <div id="userFormErrorList" class="alert alert-danger">
                <ul></ul>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="name">Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="email">Email</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            {{ csrf_field() }}
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button id="saveUser" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return false;">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Now on the same page you will need Javascript (and/or jQuery) to send an Ajax request. In this example I'm using jQuery.

**Javascript/jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Hide the contact person form error list
    $('#userFormErrorList').hide();

    // Add save handler to modal form
    $('#saveUser').on('click', function () {
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var csrf = $('input[name=_token]').val();

        var url = "{{ route('users.store') }}";
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: {
                'name': name,
                'email': email,
                '_token': csrf
            },
        }).done(function(response) {
            // Do something with the data you got.
            // For example, add the data to the screen.
        }).fail(function(response) {
            // Clear the error list, since something went wrong.
            $('#userFormErrorList ul').html('');
            // Add the returned errors to list
            var object = $.parseJSON(response.responseText);
            $.each(object, function(key, value) {
                $('#userFormErrorList ul').append('<li>' + value + '</li>');
            });
            // Show the list
            $('#userFormErrorList').slideDown();
        });
    });

    $('#userModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        // Whenever the modal is opened, focus the cursor on the name field
        $('#name').focus();
    });

});
```

Now as you can see, when someone clicks the save button, we will need to process  the data we got over Ajax.

**PHP (Controller)**

```
public function overviewUsersStore(Request $request)
    {
        /* Validate data
        *  If the validation fails, there will be sent a failed response text.
        *  This enables us to show validation errors in the view itself 
        * (check out the part about the error list in Javascript)
        */
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|confirmed|email|unique:users',
        ]);

        // Store data
        $user = New User;
        $user->name         = $request->name;
        $user->email        = $request->email;
        $user->save();

        // IMPORTANT: Just return a simple string, or object, whatever, but DON'T redirect!
        // If you redirect, you won't get a proper response on your Ajax call.
        return 'stored';
    }
```

This much should get you started properly. If you have any questions left feel free to comment.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I've managed to get it working now by following this tutorial http://www.jmkleger.com/post/ajax-crud-for-laravel-5-4

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on AJAX in order to understand how to add that kind of functionality. [The Mozilla Developer Network has some great resources to get you started.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX)

As it stands, your code is going through the standard submit-reload cycle, which is why it still reloads. Since it works (which is great), your next steps will be to add the JavaScript and refactor your server side code.

Logically, what you'll be doing is creating a function with JavaScript that will interrupt the form's standard submission process and send a separate request to the server and will consume its response. This data is generally sent in a format known as JSON.

If you're already using jQuery (which you probably are if you're using Bootstrap), you can use its [$.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function. If not, you can use something like [Axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) or even the vanilla [XMLHttpRequest](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) that's built into JavaScript. You need to tell the browser to stop the standard process, gather the data from the form, and send it to the server.

You'll then need to refactor your server-side code to not return the `redirect()` function, but rather to send a [JSON Response](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#json-responses).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the explanation, I'll improve my skills with JS although I really hate it. However, I've managed to get it working now by following this tutorial http://www.jmkleger.com/post/ajax-crud-for-laravel-5-4